# Why my Android Service is killed when I launch an Activity from it?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I have a Service that has to launch an external Activity. 
I would like that even after have launched the Activity, that Service will continue to be running. The problem is that the onDestroy() is invoked and the service is killed. 
here it is my code:

How I start the external Activity from inside the Service:

```
      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);        
      intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
      context.startActivity(intent);
```

Any idea?

Comment: add your log cat out put

Comment: there is no strange messages on the logcat. Is it normal that when I start an activity from inside a Service, that Service is being killed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it normal that when I start an activity from inside a Service, that Service is being killed?

Services are not "killed".

Your service will run until:

- You call `stopService()` referencing the service, or
- The service calls `stopSelf()`, or
- If you are using the binding pattern, all bindings (via `bindService()`) are unbound (via `unbindService()`), or
- Android terminates your process, such as due to low memory conditions or by user request

Hence, you need to determine which of the conditions is true. None necessarily have anything to do with starting an activity.

Note that starting an activity from a service is generally not a good idea, particularly if this may occur at arbitrary times rather than based on user input. Users dislike activities appearing out of nowhere.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Actually my service does 3 different operations. One of them is to start an external activity. Only this last operation invokes the onDestroy() on the service. My complete code to start the activity by package name is:
 Intent it = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
 if (null != it) {               
      it.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
      context.startActivity(it);
 }

Comment: @superbre: Starting an activity *does not cause a service to be destroyed*. All of the four bullets in my answer do. You need to determine which of those particular things is occurring.